# Node.js Webscraping Table with Slighly different values

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Trying to do some webscraing to return information from this page, and particly this rows in this table. The  one issue I see is that each of the row has some sort of a different ID and is slightly different, is there a way to dynamically webscrape these despite the fact that the class is not unique.

[image]

Comment: hit the table, then iterate the rows or cells, not everything you scrape needs unique markup.

Comment: didn't realize! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged with `cheerio`, consider the following solution:

```
// get html somehow...
var $ = cheerio.load(html)
// query all elements with class "evenrow" or "oddrow"
var $elements = $('.evenrow, .oddrow')
// handle $elements
```

Comment: oh, didn't realize you could ignore the end of the rows!